# Change timeout of CSRF Element in ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, csrf, zend-form

Please consider that I'm new to Zend.
My app defines multiple Forms. All of them extend another Form 'FormParent.php'.

FormParent.php declares a Csrf element with a timeout of 10 minutes:

```
 $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'csrf_parent',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Csrf',
            'options' => array(
                 'csrf_options' => array(
                        'timeout' => 600
                 )
            ),
    ));
```

In the views, the csrf is added with:

```
<?php echo $this->formElement($form->get('csrf_parent')); ?>
```

Now I need to set a higher timeout (15 min) just for one of the Forms, but I'm getting a little confused as I see at least 3 ways of achieving this (in the view):

1) setOptions():

```
$csrf = $form->get('csrf_parent');
$csrf->setOptions(array('csrf_options' => array('timeout' => 900)));
```

2) setCsrfValidator():

```
$csrf = $form->get('csrf_parent');
$csrf->setCsrfValidator(new Zend\Validator\Csrf(array('csrf_options' => array('timeout' => 900)));
```

3) setTimeout():

```
$validator = $form->get('csrf_parent')->getCsrfValidator();
$validator->setTimeout(900);
```

Which one should I use? All three of them?
Plus, it seems setting only one of these properties does not update the other ones, and I can end up with a CSRF such as:

```
$form->get('csrf_parent') = Zend\Form\Element\Csrf
\_ csrfValidator = Zend\Validator\Csrf
    \_ timeout = 600
\_ csrfValidatorOptions = Array[1]
    \_ [timeout] = 900
\_ options = Array[1]
    \_ [csrf_options] = Array[1]
        \_ [timeout] = 600
```

Comment: I wonder why are you creating the validation by yourself since ZF2 creates the validation automatically

Comment: He's trying to *configure* the validation that ZF2 creates.

Comment: That's correct, the CSRF validator already exists. What I want to do is to increase its timeout property to 900 (instead of 600 currently).